# Article inside report

Tags: bibliographies, multicol, article, report

I need to place an article inside a document created with the `report` class.
That means, I need a LaTeX document inside my report, where it is multicolumn'ed and the references are set in the multicolumn'ed article.

How can this be achieved?

I figured out that I can make it multicolumned by

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\end{multicols}
```

But I can not figure out how to do the same with the references.

And how can I insert figures in only one column (I know they're very small pictures)?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like a multicolumn environment as part of the outer report class, or you would like to feature a previously compiled article, as an item inside the report. Do the both have common references or seperate???

Comment: As you can see in your answer, I will like a multicolumn environemnt as a part of the outer report class (but it is a seperate chapter). Otherwise I need to create it as an other item, but I can not figure out how to do that either, if I want to keep the scaling. They have common references, but the common references should also be shown in the multicols. As I see it, I am going to create a new project, create it as a twocolumn report (need chapter) and set the page-numbering due to the other report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want, I am not sure that I understand your question.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{2em}
\hrule

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\hrule
\vspace{2em}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Some kind of, but I need to insert references into the multicolumned (different from the other text). And I need to insert figures.